# Semi Complex database query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in mysql.

- Table 1 contains a column called `app_id`
- Table 2 contains a column called `id`

I need to create a query that will show all table 1 columns for any row where `app_id` is not present in table 1's id. For example:

Table 1:

```
app_id 
1    
2    
3    
4    
5
```

Table 2:

```
id   
1    
3    
4    
5
```

So my results will be the columns of table 1 showing the `app_id=2` since that is not found in table 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
SELECT app_id FROM tableOne WHERE app_id NOT IN(SELECT id from tableTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a left join, then select rows that don't match:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.app_id = table_2.id WHERE table_2.id IS NULL;
```